# Check if XML element exist using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am parsing an XML doc into a c# project to check if an Element named "Feature" exists.
In c#, I am using what exist in the Feature Element to determine whether an if statement should run.

**XML**

```
<Projects>
 <Project>
   <Name>Test</Name>
    <Feature>AutoDev;AutoRev</Feature>
 </Project>
</Projects>
```

**C#**

```
var feature = (from project in XDocument.Load(xmlPath).Descendants("Project")                                     
where project.Element("Name").Equals(Project)                                     
select project.Element("Feature").Value).Single().Split(';');

if (names.Contains("Test"))
      //then load ticket variables....
   if (feature.Contains("AutoDev"))
      //then do this....
```

Right now I receive an error:
 **Sequence contains no elements**

Using the any method was suggested when loading Feature to check if the element exist in the array. Not sure how to implement this though.

Comment: what is `ev.PortfolioProject`..

Comment: Use `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `Single()` that way you will get a null value if nothing is found, instead of an exception.

Comment: Thanks JNYRanger, I will add and test.
Anirudh - ev.PortfolioProject grabs the Project name from the app tier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
project.Element("Name").Equals(ev.PortfolioProject)
```

should be

```
project.Element("Name").Value.Equals(ev.PortfolioProject)
                        ^
```

Comment: once added I get a differnt exception, "Duplicate Work Item"
But this will get me further along my path to completion. Thank you!

Comment: @blkhdy use First instead of Single method

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `.Value` in `project.Element("Name")`

Try this:

```
var feature = (from project in XDocument.Load(xmlPath).Descendants("Project")                                     
where project.Element("Name").Value.Equals(ev.PortfolioProject)                                     
select project.Element("Feature").Value).Single().Split(';');
```